# Nginx - how can I securely display access logfiles to public?

Tags: security, nginx

When a request comes to echolog.example.com, I want to log it.

I also want any visitor to http://echolog.example.com to be able to browse to and open the logfiles.

I'm concerned about doing this securely. Any advice on how best to configure permissions and which user should be owner of those logfiles and how to configure that?

Here is the nginx config:

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name echolog.example.com;
    access_log /opt/www/echolog.example.com.access.log;
    error_log /opt/www/echolog.example.com.error.log;
    location / {
    root /opt/www/echolog.example.com;
    autoindex on;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Being concerned about security in that matter is **a fact** since exposing logs to the public is a huge security breach, as it exposes paths, IPs and privacy is compromised. Why would you do that?

Comment: Security is contextual.  If exposing the information in the logs in itself is not a risk to the OP, then it is not a compromise.  This question is not clear however.  If exposing the logs is the goal, and the above configuration does that (if the logs are placed in the root) then what security posture are you aiming for?